# UISlider is difficult to drag in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UISlider` in `UIScrollView` and find it's difficult to drag. I have set right `contentSize` of scroll view, so the scroll view is only able to scroll vertical.

I guess there is a conflict between scroll view and slider when they detect the gesture. Does anyone have idea on this?

Comment: Hey @RayChen
Can i show code and storyboard screen shot

Comment: Please check your Scroll View Style and Will you please add some of the code here so make it more clear that

Comment: try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004419/touch-on-uislider-prevents-scrolling-of-uiscrollview

Comment: try this  in view did load

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{
    return NO;
}

Comment: @Maulikshah Thanks, I have tried this. It doesn't help.

Comment: @ColeXia, thanks. But in apple's document for this function, it said " The default returned value is YES if view is not a UIControl object; otherwise, it returns NO."